# Extract point from the following graph

Tags: extract

I have the graph that I attached below. So from a pdf file, I extracted all pictures and saved them as png files. Now I am looking at how can I get rid of the grid lines. I was thinking to get rid of the gridlines, and then to change the color of the line to red for example and then I can use WebPlotDigitazer to get the points of the line. Or someone has a better approach? Thank you very much in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwBqe.png)

Comment: Can you consider manual work ? Notice that the grid lines are necessary to obtain the coordinate references.

Comment: I have 100+ graphs so it is very time consuming

Comment: Are they all of the same type ?

Comment: They are all like this, some have multiple curves as well... I was looking to get rid of the grid and to color the curve to red for example. Then to overlap it with the original picture. That way I can select curve based on color with Web plot digitalizer

Comment: Do you need to color the different curves in different colors ? (and what in case of overlaps ?)

Comment: My idea was to get rid of these grid lines (horizontal and vertical) and this would make my job a lot easier at least

Comment: Do you need to color the different curves in different colors ? (and what in case of overlaps ?)

Comment: You need if I have multiple lines on the graph and they overlap?